# Remove corrupt Win32_Product-Entry

Tags: powershell, installation, wmi, uninstallation

I've got a service which I can't completely uninstall. Some time ago, I uninstalled it but now I realize it wasn't fully removed. The setup was created using InstallShield LE. I realized I still have it on my machine when I tried to install a new version.

If I try to install the new version it says that the old version can't be removed. I was curious because in "Programs and Features"-window there is no entry of the application. However, I checked WMI Win32_Product class and in fact, there **is** the entry of the application.

I tried to remove it using the uninstall()-method with PowerShell. I used a snippet which you can find here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa393941(v=vs.85).aspx

It didn't work as well, but at least I got a nice error message saying I can't remove it because the current state of the object is invalid (WMIMethodException).

I realized the InstallState-Column of the entry has the value 1 (advertised). I have no idea what it means and I can't find another possible solution which I could try. Unfortunately in the event log there aren't any entries that would help me. Maybe some of you know a possible way of removing it, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it still listed in registry under hklm\System\current control set\Services? Try to remove it there if present.

Answer (score 1):

If uninstallation finished in an incomplete state you'll most likely have to scrub the remainder from the Registry yourself. Check the subkeys of `{HKCU|HKLM}\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` for remaining artifacts. On 64-bit systems also check the `Wow6432Node` counterparts.