# Get-WmiObject finds 2 google chrome

Tags: powershell, google-chrome

i'm working on some updates for google chrome in my company. I have few laptops in which if i run

`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -name "Google Chrome"`

i found 2 instances of google chrome

```
IdentifyingNumber : {C5757571-346F-37C5-BD92-28783FBD2E04}
Name : Google Chrome
Vendor : Google LLC
Version : 69.244.49282
Caption : Google Chrome

IdentifyingNumber : {2981D58E-7F09-3E98-A7EF-62CA313BEEEE}
Name : Google Chrome
Vendor : Google LLC
Version : 121.0.6167.161
Caption : Google Chrome
```

while if i run only

`Get-Package -Name "Google Chrome"`
i get only one instance

```
Name    Version    Source    ProviderName
----    -------    -----    ------------
Google Chrome    121.0.6167.161    msi
```

This happens only in few machines , not in all of them . I tried to remove the 69x version with PowerShell but i had no luck.
i tried things like this

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -computer $server | Where-Object {$_.IdentifyingNumber -match "C5757571-346F-37C5-BD92-28783FBD2E04"}
$app.Uninstall()
```

Clearly i'd like a way to uninstall the version i don't want without having to uninstall everything
You might ask why ? because i'm running some reports from an SCCM script and i'm getting confused datas

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) v6+, where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. Note that WMI still _underlies_ the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Comment: It seems that `Win32_Product` also reports applications whose installation packages are present, but aren't necessarily _installed_. If you pipe to `Format-List *` you'll see properties such as `InstallLocation`, `InstallSource`, `LocalPackage` and `PackageCache`.

Comment: @mklement0, do both the WMI (Windows PowerShell) and CIM (PowerShell Core) report uninstalled packages?

Comment: @lit: Yes: The CIM cmdlets still use WMI behind the scenes, and targeting the very same class therefore reports the same instances. However, what additional properties the instances are _decorated with_ differs between `Get-CimInstance` and `Get-WmiObject`

Comment: @mklement0 you right . it doesn't seem that is installed. any idea how can i remove it ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't, @cri_pava. Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35990179/45375) helps.

Comment: It could just be an instance of an upgrade that failed to remove the old package information during the process. It's not very uncommon in Windows. However, MSI-packages are mostly very good at keeping tab on what's happening. You could try uninstalling the current version. Installing the old version and upgrading to the current again to see if the package handling gets back on track again.